# What is the best partitioning method for table where two significant columns are some IDs? The DB is Oracle 11g

Tags: database, performance, oracle11g, partitioning, database-performance

The goal is decrease time of deleting from table quering by COLUMN_1. Now this can take up to 15-30 minutes.

Currently data from table is deleted by cascade rule. COLUMN_1 is foreign key.
I would like to change this this approach to truncate whole partition in BEFORE trigger when parent row is deleted.

Besides, data is queried from application by COLUMN_2.

This two columns are in relationship presented below :

```
COL_1    COL_2
 1       1
         2
         3
         4
 2      
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
         10
 3      
         11
         12
         13
...
```

On both separately there is index.
Table has millions of records. There is a lot of insert and read actions.

After some research ([oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/part_admin.htm#BAJHFFBE)) I would use range-range partitioning
I need partitions were created dynamically, so maybe Range Interval Partitioning will be appropriate...

Comment: you could add some references to your research.

Comment: What is the goal of partitioning?  To improve load times?  To improve query times?  To implement tiered storage?  Something else?  How is the table loaded?  How is it queried?

Comment: I edited description. Thanks for the interest in question.

Comment: If the goal is to improve delete speed then you need to partition on `col_1` because that's the level of granularity you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

Switch partition N_Partition to new empty table and truncate that table:

```
    ALTER TABLE big_table
    EXCHANGE PARTITION N_partition
    WITH TABLE table_to_be_truncated
    INCLUDING INDEXES 
    WITHOUT VALIDATION 
    UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;

    TRUNCATE TABLE table_to_be_truncated
```

- Or truncate partition

```
    ALTER TABLE big_table TRUNCATE PARTITION N_partition
    UPDATE INDEXES;
```

Here is a good article describing what you can do with partitions: [Maintaining Partitions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1008226)